# ORA-12547: TNS Lost Contact when running DBCA on Oracle 11g installation on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 64 bit

Tags: oracle11g, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to create a database using DBCA on Oracle 11g installation on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 64 bit.

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.makina-corpus.org/blog/howto-install-oracle-11g-ubuntu-linux-1204-precise-pangolin-64bits), but I get

> ORA-12547: TNS Lost Contact when running DBCA.

Below are the details.  Can someone assist with the solution?

1. Instead of using `/opt/oracle`  as the "oracle" user home, I used  `/home/oracle`
2. I did not install the libstdc++5 in 32 bit version
3. I did everything else the same as the posting
4. Installation resulted in "missing packages".  I tried to do an   apt-get install for these packages from ubuntu, but ubuntu says that they don't exist.
   Then I saw in the instructions:

   > Once you will reach the "pre-reqs" screen, check "Ignore all" to continue the installation.
5. When running `./dbca` from `$ORACLE_HOME/bin`, it fails with ORA-12547.
6. I checked `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` and listener.ora , sqlnet.ora , and tnsnames.ora  all look OK.
7. However, I think that tnsnames.ora  is not being read properly, because  `./tnsping`  fails and the error message states that "EZ Connect" was used.
   But in my sqlnet.ora , I have

   ```
   names.directory_lookup = (TNSNAMES,EZCONNECT)
   ```

   It should use EZ Connect only after tnsnames is tried.
8. Also, I sometimes get ORA-12541: No listener. I tried running `./netca`.  Everything is OK until I perform a test on the listener, and it fails.
9. I can't run  `./lsnrctl`. Absolutely nothing happens for this, as well as  lsnrctl start, stop, status.
10. I can't go through sqlplus.   If I run `./sqlplus` , it asks me for username/password directly.
11. If I do  `./sqlplus / as sysdba`, then this results in "ORA-12547: TNS lost contact".
12. All environment variables are set correctly in `.bashrc`.
13. I tried re-running root.sh , but the problem is not fixed.
14. `/etc/oratab`  is OK
15. `/etc/hosts`  is OK, but I can't always ping the "localhost" or "127.0.0.1", or "ubuntu" or "127.0.1.1"

    The same TNS or Listener errors display.

Comment: "I can't always ping the "localhost" " - fix that first. Not being able to ping the machine you're on is pretty bad.

Comment: What's the solution for this? Did you found one? I have same issue

Answer (score 3):

1. When I login in oracle (sqlplus system/pass as sysdba), I got this:

   ERROR:

   ORA-12547: TNS :lost contact when try to connect to Oracle.
2. First, I think the server is down, but I check it, it is OK. And so many body say 'chmod 6751 oracle', I did it, but I got another error:

   ERROR:

   ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

   Enter user-name:
3. finally, I switch the system user from root to oracle. And I login success.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Ensure the DB is up and running and you can connect locally AS SYSDBA to the database
using Oracle binaries owner (usually oracle:oinstall Unix / Linux user). If it does not
work, probably you encounter a different problem.

1. Check privileges of an Oracle file on Unix / Linux host where database is running:
  cd $ORACLE_HOME/bin
  ls -ltr oracle

2. Change permissions as below:
  chmod 6751 oracle
  ls -ltr oracle

 This code may help you lot.
```